# ActiveX in Native C

Tags: c, activex

I have to develop an ActiveX(ocx) in native C. Can some one help me or is there any IDE for developing ActiveX in native C.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can write ActiveX controls in ANSI C.
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809982)

It's been years since I wrote a small proof, but possible. Not sure why you'd want to other than to get a real good look at a dead/dying tech.

Answer (score 0):

MS Visual Studio is what you need. Here you can find some samples: [ATL Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65t81w8a%28VS.80%29.aspx).

And as Alex said, you can use only C++ for native AX.